# Automatically identify intervals for each child if we have the sum greater than 2 in this range

Tags: excel

I have the following situation:

Whereas I have a spreadsheet with the following columns:

[image]

(ACTUALLY THE WORKSHEET HAS 10000 COLUMNS)

How to create automatically a new worksheet that indicates, for each child, the maximum waist that has been achieved and the range of weight and maximum waist achieved IF the sum of the number of exercises done for that designated range is greater than 2?

Keep in mind that the child's first and last name is not repeated

Comment: What is the expected output based on your sample data? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Perhaps you mean 10,000 ROWS? Also the child's first and last names are clearly repeated in your example? BIANCA FONSECA ...